# How to add Toast.makeText on the BookmarkActivity

Tags: android

i try add this code on bookmark Webview

```
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "you don't have internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and this

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

on this class Bookmark

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(BookmarkActivity.this,
                            listRowData, R.layout.bookmark_list_row,
                            new String[]{TAG_TITLE, TAG_LINK},
                            new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.link});

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: By the way you can not show a Toast with Application Context

Comment: Can you please explain more about your problem? Because the code you provided is all having a different functionality

Answer (score 0):

i fix my proplem

```
new LoadBookmarks().execute();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"لا يوجد اتصال بالانترنت لتحميل الملف",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Object o = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                if (o instanceof Map) {
                    Map map = (Map) o;
                    Intent in = new Intent(BookmarkActivity.this, webview.class);
                    in.putExtra("url", String.valueOf(map.get(TAG_LINK)));
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }


        }
    });
```